# Is it possible to update a LSI-9211-8i SAS HBA firmware without EFI?

Tags: boot, firmware, efi

I am trying to flash my LSI SAS HBA to IT mode from IR mode; I've heard this can't be done in the OS.
My problem is that I am using a GA-EX58-UD4P motherboard, and it doesn't seem to know anything about EFI. There is no bootable disk firmware tool, just an EFI one.

Is it possible to simply update the firmware on this card without having to buy a new computer?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.. there was a dos version in the main firmware package and just creating a bootable usb with Rufus was able to get the job done.

Feel free to delete this question.

Comment: It is helpful for me... not necessary to delete )) I am new for LSI...

Answer (score 0):

You can also update the firmware using the LSI MegaRAID Storage Manager software.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/791463)

Comment: @Mureinik How does it not answer the question?

Comment: I also believe that this is an answer. @Mureinik, I normally don’t post comments like this, but this is the third time in 24 hours that I have disagreed with one of your reviews. In [Vim: c-del in command line mode](/review/low-quality-posts/791384), you said that Matt P’s answer was not an answer. I believe that it is an answer, although it turns out not to be what the OP wanted. And [here](/review/low-quality-posts/791359 "How to preview an item in the Recycle Bin") you suggested that Donald was asking a new question, when in fact he was building on a previous answer. Please be more careful.

Comment: Stefan Thüring: Welcome to [SU] (and, yes, I know that you’ve been a member for over a year).  This answer could be improved by (1) saying how/where to get this software.  Can people download it? (from where?)  Is it part of a larger package or system? … And (2) describing how to use it.  If possible, provide a link, not ***as** an answer,* but to supplement your answer.    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.